# Using Lua libraries from within tup

Tags: lua, tup

I'm using tup to replace a complicated Makefile and I'd like to call out to other Lua libraries from my tup code. In particular. I'd like to use `luafilesystem` and `yaml` to generate build rules. However, I can't find a way to load these libraries from within tup.

In particular, if I do

```
local lfs = require "luafilesystem"
```

(or any of the other traditional variants for importing Lua scripts), I invariably get this error:

> attempt to call global '`require`' (a `nil` value)

This suggests to me that tup does not support the usual Lua mechanisms for invoking exernal libraries. Am I missing something?

I'm using tup v0.7.3-4-g1a8d07e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://gittup.org/tup/lua_parser.html) `require` is not available: "The base functions are defined, excluding dofile, loadfile, load, and require."

It seems like you may be able to implement your own "require" based on `tup.include`, which "Parses and runs the Lua file at path".

Comment: That's true, but I'd really like to be able to require binary Lua libraries as well, which is not possible with `tup.include`. In fact, I'd really like a version of `tup` without the restrictions on the Lua library.

Comment: I am not familiar with tup, but based on my reading of the documentation, this was done on purpose as they are using a modified interpreter, so probably can't guarantee compatibility with binary modules.